# Laptop WLAN adapter b/g/n/ac (1x1) Unable to Connect to 40Mhz Channel Width WiFi Network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Many of clients (smartphones, computers) can connect to this office WiFi network, but not this laptop with Realtek RTL8xxx b/g/n/ac (1x1) adapter. I forget about the radio band of the WiFi router--maybe 2.4Ghz--but it is configured with 40Mhz channel width. I don't understand, why a client with newer wlan adapter that capable to connect in 20Mhz or 40Mhz mode channel width, unable to connect to the wifi router even if the router configured running in 2.4Ghz band and 40Mhz channel width. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest drivers from HP and "forgot" the Wi-Fi network so you can re-enter the passkey?

Comment: What AP is being used? (Is it actually set to "20/40 MHz" or "40 MHz only"?)

Comment: sorry for very late reply, @ pzkpfw i believe it was the driver issue but i don't test further as it not my laptop. @ u1686 IIRC it was set to 40 Mhz only (by looking at WiFi Analyzer android app). After all i leave this problem unsolved back then, but today i face similar issue again in another laptop. About if it indeed the driver, today i found that some wlan adapter maybe 40MHz intolerant in 2.4Ghz freq. I only able to test around as client, not as wifi network admin